# In Edwin editor, how do you define something?

Tags: scheme, edwin

I'm trying to learn scheme with edwin editor on Win7.

I did (define x 3.14).  I then typed in "X".   Then I ran it using Ctrl X Ctrl E.

I get the message "unbound variable."

Answer (score 1):

You should type C-x C-e after the define. It would print back something like

`;Value: x`

Now that you have defined x, you can type x then C-x C-e, and it should say:

`;Value: 3.14`